# YouTube API v3 Search List - Keyword Phrases Returning Less Results

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

## Expected

Adding a **keyword phrase** with the **OR** operator `|` in the *YouTube API v3 [search list request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#usage)* should return more results than without a **keyword phrase** because **OR** is inclusive.

**ie:** `cryptocurrency|DigitalCash|digital+cash|dash` is passed via the `q` parameter, and is expected to return at least the same or larger size JSON response of videos compared to the search without the **keyword phrase** such as `cryptocurrency|DigitalCash|dash`.

### Documentation

The YouTube [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#usage) documentation does not mention keyword phrases explicitly for the `q` parameter.

> Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing. Similarly, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing" but not "fishing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing -fishing. Note that the pipe character must be URL-escaped when it is sent in your API request. The URL-escaped value for the pipe character is %7C.

[Implementation: Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/search) documentation mentions keyword phrases with the `skateboarding+dog` example, which is the syntax followed below using `+` in between keyword phrases' words.

## Observed

### No Keyword Phrases

Results in **40 - 43** videos after multiple tests.

**Request where** `q` **parameter equals**: `Cryptocurrency|crypto|blockchain|digitalcurrency|bitcoin|BTC|ethereum|ETH|Dash|DashNews|DigitalCash|LLMQs|ChainLocks|DAPI|MakerDao|MKR|DAI|Tezos|XTZ|ETC|Ripple|XRP|BCH|EOS|Stellar|XLM|Litecoin|LTC|Cardano|ADA|IOTA|Monero|XMR|Zcash|Tether|USDT|ChanLink|LINK|BAT|0x|ZRX|omisego|OMG|Tron|TRX|Coinbase|Binance`

**Request**: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&order=viewCount&publishedAfter=2019-05-22T23%3A30%3A04.334000000Z&q=Cryptocurrency%7Ccrypto%7Cblockchain%7Cdigitalcurrency%7Cbitcoin%7CBTC%7Cethereum%7CETH%7CDash%7CDashNews%7CDigitalCash%7CLLMQs%7CChainLocks%7CDAPI%7CMakerDao%7CMKR%7CDAI%7CTezos%7CXTZ%7CETC%7CRipple%7CXRP%7CBCH%7CEOS%7CStellar%7CXLM%7CLitecoin%7CLTC%7CCardano%7CADA%7CIOTA%7CMonero%7CXMR%7CZcash%7CTether%7CUSDT%7CChanLink%7CLINK%7CBAT%7C0x%7CZRX%7Comisego%7COMG%7CTron%7CTRX%7CCoinbase%7CBinance&safeSearch=none&type=video&pageToken=&key={yourApiKey}`

### Keyword Phrases

Results in **8** videos after multiple tests.

**Request where** `q` **parameter equals**: `Cryptocurrency|crypto|blockchain|DigitalCurrency|digital+currency|bitcoin|BTC|ethereum|ETH|Dash|DashNews|Dash+News|DigitalCash|Digital+Cash|LLMQs|ChainLock|DAPI|MakerDao|MKR|DAI|Tezos|XTZ|ETC|Ripple|XRP|BCH|EOS|Stellar|XLM|Litecoin|LTC|Cardano|ADA|IOTA|Monero|XMR|Zcash|Tether|USDT|ChainLink|LINK|BAT|0x|ZRX|omisego|OMG|Tron|TRX|Coinbase|Binance`

**Request**: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&order=viewCount&publishedAfter=2019-05-23T00%3A02%3A57.853000000Z&q=Cryptocurrency%7Ccrypto%7Cblockchain%7CDigitalCurrency%7Cdigital%2Bcurrency%7Cbitcoin%7CBTC%7Cethereum%7CETH%7CDash%7CDashNews%7CDash%2BNews%7CDigitalCash%7CDigital%2BCash%7CLLMQs%7CChainLock%7CDAPI%7CMakerDao%7CMKR%7CDAI%7CTezos%7CXTZ%7CETC%7CRipple%7CXRP%7CBCH%7CEOS%7CStellar%7CXLM%7CLitecoin%7CLTC%7CCardano%7CADA%7CIOTA%7CMonero%7CXMR%7CZcash%7CTether%7CUSDT%7CChainLink%7CLINK%7CBAT%7C0x%7CZRX%7Comisego%7COMG%7CTron%7CTRX%7CCoinbase%7CBinance&safeSearch=none&type=video&pageToken=&key={yourApiKey}`

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:java] or [tag:kotlin]?

Comment: @shmosel, The code above is implemented in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) / [Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin) running on Google Cloud's AppEngine as a **Jar**.

Comment: I don't see any code.

Comment: @shmosel, I've provided the end results above, the **API** requests which display how the code is interacting with the YouTube API.

Comment: Is the code itself relevant? If so, it should be in the question. If not, the language tags don't apply.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The API request is the most important part. I'll update the tags accordingly.